# HttpQueryServiceConfiguration always return me ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Http.h"
#pragma comment (lib,"Httpapi.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HTTPAPI_VERSION HttpApiVersion = HTTPAPI_VERSION_1;
    ULONG ret = NO_ERROR;
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    HTTPAPI_VERSION ver = HTTPAPI_VERSION_1;
    ret = HttpInitialize(ver,HTTP_INITIALIZE_SERVER|HTTP_INITIALIZE_CONFIG,NULL);
    if(ret!=NO_ERROR)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_ID configId = HttpServiceConfigIPListenList;
    HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_IP_LISTEN_QUERY* query=NULL;
    ULONG size=1000;
    ULONG re = HttpQueryServiceConfiguration(NULL,configId,NULL,NULL,query,NULL,&size,NULL);
    printf("re = %d",re);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

this re result always  is 122 (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) . I don't know reson.
this is link of HttpQueryServiceConfiguration function:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364491

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the reference you link to, the `size` you pass as a pointer to the function is `pReturnLength` which is an *output* argument and is

> A pointer to a variable that **receives** the number of bytes to be written in the output buffer.

[Emphasis mine]

The size of the buffer you provide is in the argument before, the `OutputConfigInfoLength` argument. Of course, if you want some data to be written you need to actually provide a buffer where to store it, and you pass `NULL` as that argument (`query` is initialized to `NULL`).

Also note that if the function fails with `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` the variable passed as `pReturnLength` will contain the *actual* length needed for the function to succeed. So what you should do is to first call it with a zero buffer size, to get the size needed, and then call it again to actually get the information.

Something like

```
HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_ID configId = HttpServiceConfigIPListenList;
ULONG size;
ULONG re = HttpQueryServiceConfiguration(NULL,configId,NULL,0,NULL,0,&size,NULL);

if (re != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
{
    // We got an unknown error, handle it
}
else
{
    // Allocate a buffer big enough for the data
    HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_IP_LISTEN_QUERY* query =
        reinterpret_cast<HTTP_SERVICE_CONFIG_IP_LISTEN_QUERY*>(new char[size]);

    // Call the function again
    re = HttpQueryServiceConfiguration(NULL,configId,NULL,0,query,size,&size,NULL);

    // Here you should have the information you want in `query`
    // Use the data

    // Free the memory
    delete[] query;
}
```

Comment: vs2010 compile's result  and process is good,but this function of HttpQueryServiceConfiguration show result that is not correct.Here is my code

Comment: // Here you should have the information you want in `query`
// Use the data                                       re = HttpQueryServiceConfiguration(NULL,configId,NULL,0,query,size,&size,NULL);
  printf("re = %d",re);

  struct sockaddr_storage sa = query->AddrList[1];
  struct sockaddr_in *s = (struct sockaddr_in*)&sa;
  printf("%d",sa.ss_family);
  printf("sin_addr=%s",inet_ntoa(s->sin_addr));
  printf("sin_port=%d",s->sin_port);